# error: not found: value from_avro (Databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Im trying to stream Avro data from Kafka and trying to use from_Avro by following 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/avro-dataframe.html#avro-dataframe

```
Getting error : not found: value from_avro

val df = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", servers)
.option("subscribe", "t")
.load()
.select(
from_avro($"key", SchemaBuilder.builder().stringType()).as("key"),
from_avro($"value", SchemaBuilder.builder().intType()).as("value"))

using dependencies : bijection-avro_2.12-0.9.6.jar,spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar
```

Comment: Do you use Databricks platform? It looks like `from_avro` and `to_avro` are proprietary extensions (not present in the public repository).

Comment: I'm not using Databricks platform, I used from_json which is available in public repo and looking for from_Avro.

Comment: In that you shouldn't use Databricks documentation. It is not Spark documentation.

Comment: If your messages come out of Confluent Avro, this won't work and you must define those functions using your own Decoder class

Answer (score 0):

add this import statement
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions._

Answer (score -1):

[image]import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions._

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70933624/2227743).